# Enviar datos de formulario a controlador

Tags: html

tengo el siguiente formulario que deberia enviar datos a una ruta pero no funciona el boton de envio de datos.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url ('/admin/products') }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Nombre del Producto</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                  <label class="bmd-label-floating">Precio</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Descripcion</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description">
          </div>
          
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Producto</button>
        </form>
```

esta es la ruta que tengo en la carpeta de rutas:

```
Route::post('/admin/products', 'ProductController@store');
```

esta es la funcion que deberia recibir los datos:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu boton debe ser de tipo submit ej:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Producto</button>
```

al ser de tipo **submit** se enviaran los datos del formulario por el metodo post a tu controlador.

Comment: gracias si funciono

Comment: Si te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada